# ArcScene 3D vrml export / rhino import error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, 3d-analyst, arcscene, arcgis-10.5

Arcscene does not give an error when exporting 3D (vrml) but when trying to import into Rhino, an error "" shows up. Importing into AutoCad and 3dsmax also fails. The ArcSene version is 10.5.1. Screenshots of the vrml are attached. 
Any ideas why this is happening?

[image: first page]
[image: last page]

Comment: We need more information.  Can you open the VRML in a text editor?  Is so can you check it's contents to see that ArcScene has exported anything.  Secondly, do you get any error message at all in Rhino or 3DS (if so what is it)?

Comment: thanks - added screenshots of the vrml - i was able to open in text editor. The error message in rhino is literally just "error importing untitled.wrl" and the 3ds error is "VRML read error: file does not have valid string header"

Comment: I’m with same problem... did you fixed it??